# .Net Core Vs .Net framework to create a new mvc web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I have visual studio 2015 professional editton, and i want to create my first MVC web application which should be a .net core. now i am watching an online learning demo, which mentioned to create this project:-
[image]

while inside my visual studio i have these options:-
[image]

so which option i need to chose?
second question, how i can be sure that i am using the latest version of MVC?
Thanks

Comment: There is no MVC-6, only ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 and soon 3.0 :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there is no such thing as MVC 6. It's ASP.NET Core. Second, the decision of whether to use .NET Core or .NET Framework comes down to what you need to do. .NET Core is cross-platform (Windows, Mac and Linux), whereas .NET Framework is Windows-only. .NET Core is also lighter weight, faster, and has a number of new CLR features, compared to .NET Framework. Virtually the only reason to use .NET Framework is if you have a dependency on something that utilizes Windows-specific APIs, meaning it can't be run cross-platform. Otherwise, you should always use .NET Core, if you can get away with it.

ASP.NET Core is really just a collection of NuGet packages, and like other NuGet packages, they can be updated easily. However, the difference is that these NuGet packages are generally tied to a particular version of .NET Core, and thus, the appropriate version of the packages are installed based on which version of .NET Core you're targeting. For example, if you're targeting `netcoreapp2.2` then you'll see that that packages like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` will be brought in with versions like `2.2.x`.

So, to answer your question about staying up to date, it essentially entails installing the latest version of the .NET Core SDK, and then changing your project to target that new version. Then, all the ASP.NET Core NuGet packages will naturally update accordingly.

Comment: Should be noted that VS 2015 only supports .NET Core 1.0/1.1 which (project.json) both are out of LTS support, so no further updates. VS 2015 can't handle the new csproj files. So a minimum of Visual Studio 2017 (or better 2019 for .NET Core 3.0+) is required

Comment: @Tseng yes i have noted that when i tried to create the new .net core web app inside Vs 2015 i got a message that i need to upgrade to VS2017..so i am planning to do so.. but i am not sure if i can have VS2017 + VS2015 running on the same windows 7 machine? as i already have many projects already created inside VS 2015?

Comment: Visual Studio versions can be installed side-by-side. In fact, that's just how it's done. If you no longer want 2015, for example, you must uninstall it. You can't upgrade it in place to 2017/2019. You also don't need to keep using 2015 simply because you have projects created in 2015. Any later version should be able to open any earlier version solution. It might require migrating the solution file, but I don't think that would actually occur going from 2015 to 2017/2019 (the solution file format hasn't really changed in that time period).